# Conditional typedefs

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a little peice o' code as such...

```
template <typename _T>
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef const T& ParamType;
    void DoStuff(ParamType thingy);
};
```

This can be non-optimal if `sizeof(_T) <= sizeof(_T*)`.

Therefore, I want to have a conditional `typedef`. If the size of `_T` is less than or equal to that of a pointer, just pass it in by value. Otherwise, pass it by const reference. Is this possible? I hear all this stuff about templates being turing complete but this is hurting my head.

Comment: Notice that for all reference types, `sizeof(T&)` is always `sizeof(T)` (so a comparison would not make sense).  A better way is to use `sizeof(T*)` or to stick with your previous `sizeof(void*)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite easy to achieve using [partial template specialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_template_specialization).

```
template< typename _T, bool _ByVal >
struct FooBase {
  typedef const _T& ParamType;
};

template< typename _T >
struct FooBase< _T, true > {
  typedef const _T ParamType;
};

template< typename _T, bool _ByVal = sizeof(_T) <= sizeof(void*) >
class Foo : public FooBase< _T, _ByVal > {
  typedef typename FooBase< _T, _ByVal >::ParamType ParamType;
  void DoStuff(ParamType thingy);
};
```

**EDIT** As per Jeff's sol'n one should indeed compare `sizeof(_T)` and `sizeof(_T&)` but I kept the original `<= void*` requirement.

Comment: Gave you the accepted, and jeff the upvote :)

Both were the same idea, and exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: You can skip one of the specializations by putting the typedef in the general template.

Comment: Quite correct in this case.  Also updated to allow an explicit _ByVal override at the Foo level.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that, but it's a little tricky.

My main concern here if your motive. I understand that you don't want to pass large objects by value, but whether or not the object is large is irrelevant -- what you really want to know is **how long the copy constructor takes to create the parameter**.

As a concrete example, the size of an `std::vector` is actually very tiny as it allocates all the memory on the heap and only needs a pointer. However, copying a vector takes much more time. Something like that is not something you can really include in a condition.

You're best bet here is to just pass by `const &` so that you cover the worst case. Also, I can't guarantee this, but the I believe that a compiler would be smart enough to pass by value if it thought that was more efficient.

Comment: In this case, it's for a fast NxM matrix class. However, on x86 platforms it's a bit easier to pass a double by const reference than by value. If I'm wrong, please call me on it.

Comment: @wowus - I'm assuming you've measured and have some profiling statistics showing that passing small types by value instead of const reference provides a significant speedup in your application?

Comment: I don't know whether you're right or wrong, and I'm sure it will depend on the particular CPU. What I do know is that your compiler does know, and will choose the best option for you.

Comment: Haha, if by profile dumps you mean staring at assembly dumps, then yes.

Comment: Yep. Pass by reference makes the aliasing issue a little harder for the compiler, but for an inline function, passing a byte by reference is pretty much the same as passing by value. If you empirically find that by-value is faster than by-reference in a particular case, try making a local copy of the object in the caller's scope as that can help it with aliasing+`inline` issues (while the copy operation itself is just imaginary).

Comment: @wowus, you are normally saving a dereferencing when passing by value (even if a double takes two words on 32-bit architectures) which in the long run could defer a potential cache miss.  And Chris is right, it is paramount that you profile (i.e. time) your code with both by-value and by-reference semantics, not just look at the assembly -- you may be surprised. :)

Comment: It's a good point that the size of the object alone does not give you any indication how expensive it is to copy. E.g, sizeof GCC's string is 4, which by the OP's simplistic rule would fall under the "good for copying" category.

Answer (score 4):

```
template <class T, bool Smaller>
class BestArgumentPassingType {};

template <class T>
class BestArgumentPassingType<T, true> {
  public:
    typedef T Type;
};

template <class T>
class BestArgumentPassingType<T, false> {
  public:
    typedef const T& Type;
};

template <class T>
class ArgumentType : public BestArgumentPassingType<T, sizeof(T) < sizeof(T*)> {
};

struct B { double d; double d2; };
struct S { double d; };

class A {
  public:
    static void foo(ArgumentType<B>::Type big);
    static void bar(ArgumentType<S>::Type small);
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  S s;
  A::foo(b);
  A::bar(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Like so.

Comment: You should use `T*` instead of `T&` for the sizeof test. The sizeof of a reference is that of the referenced type.

Comment: Hmm.  I found that sentence in the standard, but it doesn't jibe with gcc's implemented behavior in 4.4.3 -- I find `sizeof(char)` is different from `sizeof(char&)`, which is the same as `sizeof(char*)`.  Wonder what's up here -- compiler bug?

Comment: I tested with GC4.4.3, GCC4.5 (svn) and GCC4.1 - all output sizeof 1 for `char&`. References are supposed to be transparent (similar for `typeid`).

Comment: Aha, I see the problem: I was shortcutting by using gdb on a 64-bit binary and then using `p sizeof(char&)`, which produces a different value than g++ actually produces when simply printf-ing `sizeof`s.  Sigh, bugs.

Comment: um that's disgusting behavior of gdb. I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Boost call traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm).

```
template <typename _T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void DoStuff(boost::call_traits<_T>::param_type thingy);
};
```

From the documentation:

> If T is a small built in type or a pointer, then param_type  is defined as T const, instead of T const&.

Comment: That doesn't do what he wants to do. It does avoid some other problems though, so I guess it's kind of relevant.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Hmm, do you know how it's implemented? I just want to grab the relevant parts instead of pulling in all of boost.

Comment: @Poita_ - other then the exact rule of when it's a value or a reference, it's exactly what he's looking for.

Comment: @wowus - it's done via template forwarding and specialization.  For boost code, it's actually pretty easy to follow: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/detail/call_traits.hpp

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not directly what you asked for, but it's your goal. I would use a different way to achieve this: Pass classes (this includes structs and unions) by reference, and pass everything else by value.

```
template<typename>
struct tovoid { typedef void type; };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct parm_type {
  typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct parm_type<T, typename tovoid<int T::*>::type> {
  typedef T const& type;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    typedef typename parm_type<T>::type ParamType;
    void DoStuff(ParamType thingy);
};
```

This implements the (in my opinion) very good point that @Poita_ made.