# How to make a conditional typedef in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

typedef int Integer;

#if sizeof(Integer) <= 4
    typedef std::mt19937     Engine;
#else
    typedef std::mt19937_64  Engine;
#endif

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(Integer) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but I get this error:

```
error: missing binary operator before token "("
```

How can I correctly make the conditional typedef?

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't know anything about `sizeof`, or other C++ constructs. It _certainly_ doesn't know about things you created yourself with `typedef`, as that hasn't even been parsed yet.

Comment: You could use `enable_if` or `conditional` to conditionally define typedefs, but you can't use preprocessor for that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Preprocessing and compilation are integrated in GCC, so it is not only not certain that the software processing code does not know about user-created type definitions but known to be false in the case of GCC. The reason `sizeof` cannot work in a preprocessor conditions is because the language is defined that way, not because of how an implementation works.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The language is defined such that preprocessing occurs in an earlier translation phase. Your story about how GCC could theoretically figure it out is not relevant, for the exact reason you stated: it's an implementation detail.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The translation phases define syntax and semantics, not order of processing. Per C++ 2011 (N3092) 2.2 [lex.phases] note 11, “Implementations must behave as if these separate phases occur, although in practice different phases might be folded together.” My point about GCC is relevant because it demonstrates that your claim that this is how an implementation works is wrong. In other words, your comment **claims** that a particular method of implementation prevents this. But it is not implementation that prevents this (we **could** do it); it is the language definition.

Comment: @Eric: I didn't mean to claim anything about implementations whatsoever. I certainly didn't mention any particular one. My comment stated a behaviour that is subject to the as-if rule, just as do yours. I don't think we're actually disagreeing on anything here — your language lawyering might as well have come straight from the mirror. :)

Comment: Also see [Change member-typedef depending on template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24053582/608639) and [Conditional typedefs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2349578/608639)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use the [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) meta-function from C++11.

```
#include <type_traits>  //include this

typedef std::conditional<sizeof(int) <= 4,
                         std::mt19937,
                         std::mt19937_64>::type Engine;
```

Note that if the type which you use in `sizeof` is a template parameter, say `T`, then you have to use `typename` as:

```
typedef typename std::conditional<sizeof(T) <= 4, // T is template parameter
                                  std::mt19937,
                                  std::mt19937_64>::type Engine;
```

Or make `Engine` depend on `T` as:

```
template<typename T>
using Engine = typename std::conditional<sizeof(T) <= 4, 
                                         std::mt19937,
                                         std::mt19937_64>::type;
```

That is **flexible**, because now you can use it as:

```
Engine<int>  engine1;
Engine<long> engine2;
Engine<T>    engine3; // where T could be template parameter!
```

Comment: +1 Minor nitpick: Checking for `sizeof(int) <= 4` is perhaps not a very portable way since on a 64-bit Windows machine, GCC (MinGW) x64 compiler gives `sizeof(int) = sizeof(long) = 4`. A better way would be `sizeof(void*) <= 4`.

Comment: @legends2k: You mean `Engine<void*> engine4;`? ;-)

Comment: @Nawaz: Of course not :) I meant `std::conditional<sizeof(void*) <= 4, std::mt19937, std::mt19937_64>` in the first code snippet.

Comment: @legends2k: Why would you use that if I've provided you with `Engine<void*>`? :P

Comment: @Nawaz: Haha... that's true. However, I thought the OP should probably know the pitfall in detecting the architecture based on the size of an `int` :)

Answer (score 37):

Using [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) you can do it like so:

```
using Engine = std::conditional<sizeof(int) <= 4, 
                               std::mt19937, 
                               std::mt19937_64
                               >::type;
```

If you want to do a `typedef`, you can do that too.

```
typedef std::conditional<sizeof(int) <= 4, 
                         std::mt19937, 
                         std::mt19937_64
                         >::type Engine
```

Comment: There's no need for `typename` here

Comment: @gx_ Yeah, used to putting it there from working with templates, not concrete types.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I fixed it a little.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have C++11 available (although it appears you do if you're planning to use `std::mt19937`), then you can implement the same thing without C++11 support using the [Boost Metaprogramming Library (MPL)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html). Here is a compilable example:

```
#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

struct foo { };
struct bar { };

int main()
{
    typedef mpl::if_c<sizeof(int) <= 4, foo, bar>::type Engine;

    Engine a;
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
}
```

This prints the mangled name of `foo` on my system, as an `int` is 4 bytes here.

Comment: Why don't you use `if_c` instead? It would be must easier to write (and understand) : `mpl::if_c<sizeof(int)<=4, foo, bar>::type`. Isn't it?

Comment: @Nawaz: Indeed, that is better in a number of ways. I had forgotten about `mpl::if_c`. I updated the example to use that approach instead.