# How can I create a trait to give me the larger of two types?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I need to check if one type is larger than other, and then conditionally use either one type or the other. in terms of bytes.

something like this(pseudo code):

```
template<typename T, typename U>
using Larger = sizeof(T) > sizeof(U) ? T: U; // ??
```

We assume both types are either signed, unsigned of floating types.

Comment: `using Larger = std::conditional<sizeof(T) > sizeof(U), T, U>::type;` https://stackoverflow.com/a/17854463/995714

Comment: @phuclv I think I tried that, but omitted parantheses just like you and that didn't compile.

Comment: Unfortunately we could not peer review that wrong answer because it was posted in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it!

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
using Larger = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(T) > sizeof(U)), T, U>;
```

[`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) is what you need for conditionally selecting types.