# C++ Conditional typedef with more than two type

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am trying to do something like this .

```
if (flow1)
  {
     typedef template_class<user_defined_type1> x;
  }
else if (flow2)
  {
     typedef template_class<user_defined_type2> x;
  }
else if (flow3)
  {
     typedef template_class<user_defined_type3> x;
  }
else 
  {
     typedef template_class<user_defined_type4> x;
  }
```

I checked the answers for this question [How to make a conditional typedef in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854407/how-to-make-a-conditional-typedef-in-c)  but I'm not sure how I can use std::conditional if I have more than 1 type ? Is it even possible to do something like this ?

Comment: Are flow1 etc compile time constants?

Comment: Yes, nest `std::conditional`s.

Answer (score 4):

Juse use multiple nested `std::conditional`, eg:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

using x = std::conditional<flow1,
        template_class<user_defined_type1>,
        std::conditional<flow2,
            template_class<user_defined_type2>,
            std::conditional<flow3,
                template_class<user_defined_type3>,
                template_class<user_defined_type4>
            >::type
        >::type
    >::type;

/* or, using std::conditional_t in C++14:
using x = std::conditional_t<flow1,
        template_class<user_defined_type1>,
        std::conditional_t<flow2,
            template_class<user_defined_type2>,
            std::conditional_t<flow3,
                template_class<user_defined_type3>,
                template_class<user_defined_type4>
            >
        >
    >;
*/
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

using x = template_class<
    std::conditional<flow1,
        user_defined_type1,
        std::conditional<flow2,
            user_defined_type2,
            std::conditional<flow3,
                user_defined_type3,
                user_defined_type4
            >::type
        >::type
    >::type
>;

/* or, using std::conditional_t in C++14:
using x = template_class<
    std::conditional_t<flow1,
        user_defined_type1,
        std::conditional_t<flow2,
            user_defined_type2,
            std::conditional_t<flow3,
                user_defined_type3,
                user_defined_type4
            >
        >
    >
>;
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can nest `std::conditional`:

```
                       //  if (flow1) -> type1
using x = std::conditional_t<flow1, template_class<user_defined_type1>,
                       // else if (flow2) -> type2 
                   std::conditional_t< flow2, template_class<user_defined_type2>,
                       // else if (flow3) -> type3                             
                       std::conditional_t<flow3,template_class<user_defined_type3>,
                       // else -> type4
                            template_class<user_defined_type4>>>>
```

This of course only works when `flow` is a constant expression.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `flow` needs to be a compile time constant

Answer (score 0):

Here's my little refresher on C++ that solves this generically by reduction to tuple indexing (Oops, C++17 needed).

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>

// helper function
template <bool First, bool ... Rest>
constexpr auto first_true_index() -> size_t
{
    if constexpr(First)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if constexpr(sizeof...(Rest) == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + first_true_index<Rest...>();
    }
}

// input
struct type1 {};
struct type2 {};
struct type3 {};
struct type4 {};
constexpr bool flow1 = false, flow2 = true, flow3 = true;

// implementation
using types = std::tuple<type1, type2, type3, type4>;
constexpr auto index = first_true_index<flow1, flow2, flow3>();
using selected_type = std::tuple_element_t<index, types>;

// test
static_assert(std::is_same_v<selected_type, type2>);

int main()
{
}
```